# Reuse facebook comment box

Tags: html, facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I created a facebook comment box for my website using the latest api.Also added app_id meta tag.

Script

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=199129063943947";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Here is the code for my page.I generated the script using this page.

It worked great and is linked to my app.But when i try to reuse the same code for another page in same domain it is not linked to my app.

For example

Is it necessary to generate code for different pages individually its quite annoying.How can i avoid it?

Comment: You mean you want to use it on different domains? Facebook limits the domains you can use the JS SDK on to the domains you have specified in app settings. You can only really specify multiple domains, if they have the same “base name” - so if you had foobar.com, foobar.co.uk, foobar.de etc, you would be able to add those; but for completely different domains, you will have to set up different apps.

Comment: no same domain.I want use on different webpages in same domain..Like website.com/page1.php,website.com/page2.php

Comment: Then I don’t understand what you are asking. (Especially since you have shown the code that embeds the JS SDK only, and not even the part that actually “creates” the comment plugin.) What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i have updated the question.i generated the code using website mywebsite.com/contact.php it is working...but when i use it another page mywebsite.com/contact2.php where is changed the data-href it is loading but i lost moderator panel..

Comment: Well then your contact2.php is most likely missing the proper Open Graph meta data, that specifies that you are allowed to moderate the comments for that particular URL in the first place.